# Materialize - AutoComplete hiding when changing data with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete, materialize

I'm making a form using MaterializeCSS and jQuery. I got 2 fields : `Name` and `ID`.

The field Name is an AutoComplete field that gets the right data. The ID field is not important.

I'm trying to implement a functionality to get data as the user writes.

The problem occurs when the user writes : the data "behind" the AutoComplete is changing properly, but the dropdown component of the AutoComplete hides. The user must click outside of the AutoComplete field and click back on it to see the changes, which is absolutely not user-friendly.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  //Autocomplete
  $(function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1',
      success: function (response) {
        var nameArray = response.data;
        var dataName = {};
        console.log('nameArray = ' + JSON.stringify(nameArray, 4, 4));
        for (var i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {
          dataName[nameArray[i].last_name] = nameArray[i].flag;
        }
        console.log('dataName = ' + JSON.stringify(dataName, 4, 4));
        $('#name_autocomplete').autocomplete({
          data: dataName,
          limit: 5, // The max amount of results that can be shown at once. Default: Infinity.
        });
      }
    });
  });
});


$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#name_autocomplete').keyup(function () {
    $(function () {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2',
        success: function (response) {
          var nameArray = response.data;
          var dataName = {};
          console.log('nameArray = ' + JSON.stringify(nameArray, 4, 4));
          for (var i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {
            dataName[nameArray[i].last_name] = nameArray[i].flag;
          }
          console.log('dataName = ' + JSON.stringify(dataName, 4, 4));
          $('#name_autocomplete').autocomplete({
            data: dataName,
            limit: 5, // The max amount of results that can be shown at once. Default: Infinity.
          });
        }
      });
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<main>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="main_panel_form" class="card-panel col s12">
            <div class="row">
                <form class="col s12" action="/test">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s4">
                            <input id="name_autocomplete" name="name_autocomplete" type="text" class="autocomplete">
                            <label id='label_name_autocomplete' for="name_autocomplete" class="active">Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s3">
                            <input id="id" name="id" type="text" class="autocomplete">
                            <label id="label_id" for="id">ID</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row center-align">
                        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

On this example, when the user starts to write, it gets new data (from ?page=1 to ?page=2)

I'd like to see the data of the AutoComplete change while it remains opened.

I've also made an example on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Fuzzy5/pen/rvMJLv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AutoComplete component hides each time the user writes because you initialize `#name_autocomplete` for each `keyup`. Each time the `init` function is called, it closes the autocomplete suggestions.

Materialize has a specific method `updateData` to refresh the initial object provided: http://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html

I took your codePen and refactored it so you can have an example of the autocomplete method `updateData`. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/LauraBelavoir/pen/VxKdZN?editors=1111)

Comment: Are you sure this is working ?

Chrome DevTools's console tells that updateData is not a function, and the input is not getting modified

Your code looks great else :)

Comment: I actually found out. Here is the code : https://codepen.io/Fuzzy5/pen/jxMJYX
JQuery couldn't find the method updateData so I used the native Javascript syntax :

    const input_autocomplete = document.querySelector('#name_autocomplete');
    let instance = M.Autocomplete.getInstance(input_autocomplete);
 
It works now, thanks man :)

Comment: Exact I have just updated my codePen to get the Materialize instance.

Comment: @Laura can you provide a version with the chips autocomplete ?